# jQuery Cycle plugin z-index float problem

Tags: jquery, html, css, cycle

When I try to place an element on top of my jQuery Cycle element, it doesn't work. The element is always behind the jQuery cycle element. I use float: right; to position the element, and set its z-index to 100000, to no avail.

Firebug sees the Cycle element and its children as having low z-indexes, and shows the floating element to be in the right place.

The element never shows above the Cycling images.

```
<!-- the cycling set -->
<div id='headerimages'>
    <img src='images/header1.jpg' alt='' style='' />
    <img src='images/header2.jpg' alt='' style='' />
    <img src='images/header3.jpg' alt='' style='' />
</div>
<!-- the floating element -->
<img src='images/logotransparent.png' alt='' id='logo' />
```

Comment: This question has some interesting 'answers' for people >= 10k rep :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

floating doesn't trigger z-index, only

`Position: Relative` and `position: Absolute`

so try these.. you might want to try adding `position:relative`,

 
it won't effect anything most of the time, but will give you access to **z-index**

Comment: Thank you! CSS doesn't gel with my head. It's so high level, but seems to have really finicky requirements. I don't quite understand it and am the first to admit it. Your solution worked perfectly. Any idea why an element needs that? I though position: relative; was the default?

Comment: no, position: static is the default. its that the laws of the CSS world, that says that only relative and absolute have z-index. it kind of makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old thread....but thought to put it here.....I used the presentationcycle in my site and faced similar problem, tried out the solution suggested here.....I changed the Z-index at many places in my own css files....but finally found that the problem was in the css of the cycle itself.....changing the z-index in it helped to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but the final fix for me was setting the z-index on the things I wanted to float above my animation to a really high number (100 in my case). It appears that Cycle assigns it's own z-indexes (they were in the single digits, but still greater than 1 or 2, which is where I initially set my floating objects' z-indexes).

Answer (score 0):

Just add z-index style to cycle container

```
.cycle-slideshow {
 z-index: 0; // or any smaller value to the covered div's
}
```

details see [Displaying a div at a z-index above a jQuery Cycle slide show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736481/displaying-a-div-at-a-z-index-above-a-jquery-cycle-slide-show)